# Se podria usar el codigo numero 1 en Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, input

El codigo que esta en el numero 1 permite que a la hora de pegar en mi input solo se pueda pegar numeros y que no se pueda pegar ni letras ni caracteres especiales dentro del input

1. Este es el codigo que quiero usar y pasarlo a Angular

   ```
     function process(input){
       let value = input.value;
       let numbers = value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");
       input.value = numbers;
     }


     <input type="text" oninput="process(this)">
    ...
   ```
2. Asi es como lo uso en Angular en el HTML y en el .TS

HTML

```
 ...
 <input (input)="process($event)" type="text"/>
 ...
```

.TS

```
 ...
 process(input){
     let value = input.value;
     let numbers = value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");
     input.value = numbers;
   }
 ...
```

3. Cuando ejecuto el código me aparece el error de que no encuentra el valor que se pone en el input

Comment: ¿Has pensado en usar [`<input type="number" />`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number)?. El navegador hará el trabajo por ti de una manera más elegante, aunque permite decimales.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Has realizado la conversión de código de manera errónea.

En la función original llamas a `process(this)` usando `this` como parámetro, por lo que el parámetro `input` de la función apuntará al elemento `<input>` del DOM que la ha llamado (un [`HTMLInputElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement)) y, por lo tanto, `input.value` apunta a su valor.

Sin embargo en Angular estás llamando a `process($event)`, donde `$evento` será un evento de tipo [`InputEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/InputEvent).

Todos los eventos que heredan de [`Event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) tienen una propiedad llamada `target` que apunta al elemento del DOM que ha generado el evento.

Al ser un elemento `<input>` el contenido de `target` será de tipo [`HTMLInputElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement), en el que puedes encontrar la propiedad `value` que tenías en tu código original.

En Typescript es mejor respetar e indicar explícitamente los tipos de datos para que todo funcione correctamente de antemano y sin sorpresas.

La función que deberá atender al evento podría ser la siguiente:

```
/* El parámetro es un evento de un campo input */
process(evento: InputEvent) {
    /* Obtenemos el elemento input sobre el que se generó el evento */
    let elemento: HTMLInputElement = <HTMLInputElement>evento.target;
    /* Eliminamos caracteres no permitidos */
    elemento.value = elemento.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");
}
```

Puedes verlo en funcionamiento en el siguiente enlace:

- https://codesandbox.io/s/red-snow-6v3z4r?file=/src/app/app.component.ts:188-525

Comment: Muchas gracias Oscar, me ayudaste un montón, gracias

Comment: De nada, he aprovechado para ampliar la explicación con más detalles. Te aconsejo que te acostumbres a indicar los tipos. Por un lado te ayudará a entender mejor lo que estás haciendo y por otro lado podrás enterarte de antemano cuándo no funcionará algo por estar haciéndolo de manera incorrecta.